# Why doesn't the number of active threads pass 3 in this recursive thread example?

Tags: java, multithreading

I tried to write a programme for testing the effect of the execution of parent/child threads in java! why is the number of the active threads below 3? What happens to the other threads. It makes me think that Java can have millions of threads but only a few of them can be active. Is that correct or is there something else?

```
public class ManyThreadsTester {
    static int threadCount = 0;
    static class recursiveRunnable implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(threadCount);
            // Arrives up to infinity if the System.exit(0) statement is absent!
            try {
                System.out.println("Active threads before: " + Thread.activeCount());
                //Always prints 2
                Thread.sleep(40);
                threadCount++;
                new Thread(new recursiveRunnable()).start();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ManyThreadsTester.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            System.out.println("Active threads after: " + Thread.activeCount());
            //Always prints 3
        }


    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException{
        Thread th = new Thread(new recursiveRunnable());
        th.start();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.print("FINAL ACTIVE THREAD COUNTS: " + Thread.activeCount());
        //prints 2
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get three or two for active threads?  Unclear if your title is inclusive or not, but it seems in your code you wrote "prints 2." So I'll assume you mean it never returns more than 2 as the active thread count. Which likely also means that you are running this code on a dual core machine. See: [Multi-threading, how does concurrent threads work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243682/multi-threading-how-does-concurrent-threads-work)

Comment: @turbo if you read the code comments well you see that the "Active threads after:" prints always 3 and the "Active threads before:" prints always 2! so It never passes 3!

Comment: Ah I missed that, my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you threads immediately quit after spawning children. You would get higher numbers if you add a delay at the end:

```
new Thread(new recursiveRunnable()).start();
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

Output:

```
...
Active threads before: 30
28
Active threads before: 31
29
Active threads before: 32
30
...
```

Comment: Ja! That's it the problem. However now I wonder how java can manage all these threads. changing the numbers I could arrive to 50,000  active threads(and maybe more)! It can cause a significant starvation in real world programming.

Comment: This amount of concurrent threads would be a severe problem for JVM. To avoid it data can be organize and submitted in batches to thread pools. Thread pools cap the amount of active threads and reuse them for submitted jobs.